# Spritesheet: tool to get coordinates

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a one spritesheet image with all sprites, I downloaded this image from Interent. My question: Is there a tool that help me to get the coordinates of each sprite? would I have to search coordinates manually ?

I've been reading several tutorials like:http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d and http://indiedevstories.com/2011/04/10/using-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d-and-tiled-part-1/, but all them use multiple images to create one spritesheet and generate automatically the .plist, but this is not my case.

In my case I have only one .png and no .plist

Help me please!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can crop the images using some editor (photoshop for example) and then use the exiting tool to generate the texture and the plist. I think it will be the fastest and the easiest way because in case you would want to generate only plist you will do the same operation - selecting the rectangle.

Answer (score 4):

Apologies for the self-promotion but I have created a tool for working with single spritesheet images and outputting the coordinates. It even has automatic sprite selection :)

http://www.darkfunction.com/editor

Comment: The link is dead, try this one: http://darkfunction.com/editor/

Answer (score 0):

Use preview to crop out all the images separately. Then use zwoptex or texture packer to combine them all and generate the spritesheet with .png and .plist

Other than that it is difficult to figure out what is the rect of each image. If you are a good programmer you can write a tool to analyze the png and extract out the information which can be used to identify the rectangles, but my advice is to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Divide your image using an image editor. Then add it to a spritesheet generator (like [Sprite Master](http://www.mobinodo.com/spritemaster)). Then you are free to make your output as you want by just changing the parameters.

Sprite Master will have a feature like parsing prepared spritesheet to individual images in following versions.